# How do i retrieve query result only if there are results in child relationships? or - how to remove empty strings results in child relatioship?

Tags: soql

I have a few accounts, i want to select only the accounts that have an Id of a specific contact.

this is my query:

```
Select Name, (Select Id From Contacts Where Id='0035E000007Qg2cQAC') From Account a
```

and i receive this result:

[image]

i want to see in the result only the row with a result in "Contacts", and remove all the rows with an empty string. in this case, i want to see only the second row, with "Child Contacts (1)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with left inner join, you can add filter using left outer join like below:

```
SELECT Name, 
    (SELECT Id FROM Contacts 
        WHERE Id = '0035E000007Qg2cQAC') 
FROM Account 
WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact)
```

Comment: Actually the latter sub-query in the above is a `Left Inner Join`, the former a `Left Outer Join`.

Comment: thanks for clarifying @AdrianLarson, Silly me, I always get confused with them! Edited the answer.

Comment: I often refer back to [A Deeper look at SOQL and Relationship Queries on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com) when discussing joins.

Comment: Am I missing something? How could it be possible that a contact have multiple account ids related? Why not just using: `SELECT Account.Name FROM Contact WHERE Id = '0035E000007Qg2cQAC'`

Comment: @MartinLezer maybe i didnt explain myself correctly, i just wanted to have the other rows with no results missing. i cant do the query you suggested because i need an account with the related contact, not simply a contact.
and in fact, the scenario you proposed, having a contact with multiple account ids is possible, if the company has partners.

Comment: @D.Griff In your question you said that you want to remove all the rows without the contact found. It's the same than the query I just posted.

Comment: @D.Griff The point is that `Contact` to `Account` is a many-to-one relationship. If you filter on the `Contact.Id`, there can only possibly be one matching `Account`. It's an odd filter to place in these circumstances.

Comment: @AdrianLarson i dont understand why is it odd. i get it now that there is only one match, but if i want only one result, i need to remove the rest of the rows...

Comment: and sorry, im new to SOQL, its counter intuitive compared to SQL server, so i think its legit to ask these kind of questions :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get Account related to your contact by executing this query

```
Account acc = [Select Name,(Select Id from Contacts) from Account where Id IN (Select AccountId from Contact where Id = '0035E000007Qg2cQAC' )];
```